# How to Filter a Bean from List of List of Beans with exceptions handled in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a two Bean Classes : User and Post.

User have the following members:

```
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Date birthDate;
private List<Post> userPosts;
```

Post have the following members:

```
private Integer id;
private String title;
private Date postDate;
```

I want to extract one post for a corresponding user.
The methods will have the userId and postId as input.
How can I convert the following logic in Java 8?

```
public Post findOnePost(int userId, int postId) {
    boolean isUserFound = false;
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getId() == userId) {
            isUserFound = true;
            for (Post post : user.getUserPosts()) {
                if (post.getId() == postId) {
                    return post;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isUserFound) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("userId- " + userId);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
   users
            .stream()
            .findFirst(user -> user.getId().equals(userId))
            .orElseThrow(new PostNotFoundException("userId- " + userId))
            .flatMap(user -> user.getPosts().stream())
            .findFirst(post -> post.getId() == postId)
```

You can use something like this, it returns `Optional`

Comment: I have just edited the question to add a condition in between to throw an exception. Could you please add that too to your logic. Thanks

Comment: @NivinJohn done, but one suggestion, your method is named findOnePOst and it throws UserNotFoundException, which is not a good design :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and i totally agree with it. I created it just for testing purpose. This is not exactly the business code.