# Filter a Bean from List of List of Beans with exceptions handled in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a two Bean Classes : User and Post.

User have the following members:

```
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Date birthDate;
private List<Post> userPosts;
```

Post have the following members:

```
private Integer id;
private String title;
private Date postDate;
```

I want to extract one post for a corresponding user.
The methods will have the userId and postId as input.
How can I convert the following logic in Java 8?

```
public Post findOnePost(int userId, int postId) {
    boolean isUserFound = false;
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getId() == userId) {
            isUserFound = true;
            for (Post post : user.getUserPosts()) {
                if (post.getId() == postId) {
                    return post;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isUserFound) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("userId- " + userId);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Filter a Bean from List of List of Beans with exceptions handled in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391418/how-to-filter-a-bean-from-list-of-list-of-beans-with-exceptions-handled-in-java)

Comment: This question was asked by me. I was unable to find a right answer there.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate. This is not duplicate

Comment: I know it is your question. It is the same as this one, The last one got flagged as duplicate, so i think this one is a duplicate also. You edited your question by adding the UserNotFoundException, but I assume you didn´t even try to solve this small addition to the original question by yourself. Outgoing from the duplicated question provided as a link in your first post it is really only a small step to the solution. Take a look at Optional orElseThrow for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to throw UserNotFoundException, when user does not exist, but return null, when user is not containing desired post:

```
List<User> foundUsers = users.stream()
.filter(user -> Objects.equals(user.getId(), userId));
.collect(toList());
if(foundUsers.isEmpty()){
 throw new UserNotFoundException("userId- " + userId);
}
return foundUsers.stream().map(User::getUserPosts)
.flatMap(List::stream)
.filter(post-> Objects.equals(user.getId(), userId))
.findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Otherwise it can be simplified to single stream:

```
public Optional<Post> findOnePost(int userId, int postId) {
    return users.stream()
      .filter(user -> Objects.equals(user.getId(), userId)) // find user
      .flatMap(user-> user.getUserPosts().stream()) // extract posts
      .filter(post-> Objects.equals(post.getId(), postId)) //filter posts
      .findFirst(); // find first matching
 }
```

Return Optional instead of null or an Exception. Class using this method will decide, to throw an exception or not. Secondly it's harmful to return null value, this may cause problems.

Using `Objects.equals(a,b)` will check for null values, preventing NPE

Comment: I see two problem with your code `flatMap(user- user.getUserPosts().stream()) // extract posts` here you have missing `>` and also `.filter(post-> Objects.equals(user.getId(), userId)) //filter posts` should filter based on post not user.

Comment: Thank you @Pankaj. I have fixed my answer, thank to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Even though earlier answer is accepted, I'll provide mine as you added have asked for condition `if (!isUserFound) {throw new UserNotFoundException("userId- " + userId);}`. I think, variable `isUserFound` and exception `UserNotFoundException` is misleading because what you want is to throw exception when no matching user and post is found.

```
public Post findOnePost(int userId, int postId) throws UserNotFoundException {
    return users.stream()
        .filter(user -> Objects.equals(user.getId(), userId))
        .flatMap(user -> user.getUserPosts().stream())
        .filter(post -> Objects.equals(post.getId(), postId))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("userId- " + userId));
  }
```

I'm assuming `UserNotFoundException`is checked exception, if not remove from method declaration.